# Using list items as keys in a python dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, key

I'm working with a large CSV file in python and I'm trying to create a dictionary based on lists of text tied to a unique identifier. In the CSV, the values in each cell of the Items column were originally free text and are now comma separated lists. The data looks like this:

```
ID      Items
123     'A', 'B', 'C'
234     'A', 'C', 'D'
567     'A', 'D', 'E', 'F'
```

I'm trying to get a count of the unique identifiers for each element in the Items column (i.e. How many unique IDs have A, how many have B). Is there a way to create a dictionary with the items as the keys? Like this:

`{'A': 123, 234, 567
 'B': 123
 'C': 123, 234
 'D': 234, 567}`

I am trying to use a for loop. First I identify the column of the csv I want to use--i.e. Items (10). Then I want to loop through each element of the list.

```
dict = {}        
reader = csv.reader(inF)
for row in reader:
    items = row[10]
        for x in items:
            if x not in dict:
                  dict[x] += x
```

Comment: Sure, that's very possible.

Comment: Show us what you tried and how it didn't work.  There are multiple ways this could be done.

Comment: I added some code that is both incomplete and incorrect...I'm just not sure where to go from here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the file format you gave, this will work. But depending on what edge cases you have you may have to modify the regexs. I didn't use the csv reader because for this case a regex seemed easy enough not to.

```
# import regular expressions
import re

itemLookup = dict()
file = 'data.csv'
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # split rows on either ', ' or ' '
        columns = re.split(',? +',  line)

        # only process row if it starts with a number
        id_mo = re.search('^\d+$', columns[0])
        if id_mo:
            # get the id number (first column)
            # and convert it from a string to an integer
            id = int(id_mo.group(0))

            # for the rest of the columns in this row
            for col in columns[1:]:
                # search for the get item name  in the column
                # (without quotes or new lines)
                # i.e. i'm assuming item name matches this regex
                item_mo = re.search('\w+', col)

                # ignore empty columns
                if item_mo:
                    # get the item name that we just searched for
                    item = item_mo.group(0)

                    # if we have not come across this item name before
                    if item not in itemLookup:
                        # then create it, and assign it an empty list
                        itemLookup[item] = []
                    # add the id to the list referenced by the item name
                    itemLookup[item].append(id)

print(itemLookup)
```

output:

```
{   'A': [123, 234, 567], 
    'C': [123, 234], 
    'B': [123], 
    'E': [567], 
    'D': [234, 567], 
    'F': [567]
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! This is very helpful!